# What are the options, with +vs and -vs, for store and retrieval of 400-500k fields of user data?

Tags: php, sql, xml, database, csv

**Context**

I'm implementing a website to help people learn a foreign language.

I'm working in PHP and PDO. My database backend is MySQL. (For those who are interested, the front end is all done in HTML5, CSS and Javascript.)

The essence of this question is how to best planning/structure the backend of a web app which requires storing lots of individual items of data for many users.

**What I Have Already, and What I Want to Do**

I have four database tables:

1. Contains every word of a corpus of texts in the language, with lemma
   and morphological tagging. (350,000+ rows)
2. Contains dictionary of words, with lemma numbers that match table 1. (6-7,000 rows)
3. Contains list of grammar morphemes that need to be learnt. (500-1,000 rows)
4. Contains list of users.

I want users to have a score for how well they know every word in the corpus. For each word:

1. Score for recognition of lexeme meaning.
2. x3 different scores for different aspects of grammar parsing relevant to this
   particular language.

I also want users to have a score for how well they know the different grammar morphemes. In other words, for each user, I want to store and retrieve up to 400-500k fields.

**What I Would Like to Know**

I'm pretty sure that I can't store all this data for each user in a database table, because the number of columns required far exceeds the maximum allowed in SQL (from my research: 1k, or maybe 4k on some systems).

At present, the only options I know about are storing the data in an xml file for each user, or in a csv file for each user.

What are my options? What are the +ves and -ves of these options? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend using (a) join table(s):

- Word ID
- User ID
- Lexeme Score
- x3 grammar Score

With a PK of `(UserID, WordID)` (and maybe a secondary key on WordID) you get a table, that has a max of 350k*Usercount rows, accessed only (or mostly) via PK, with close-to-perfect index locality, which seems quite manageable.

**Edit**

Assuming, the word and user tables each have an integer PK called `id` and the score is a positive int , to create your join table you would need

```
CREATE TABLE scores (
  wordID INT NOT NULL,
  userID INT NOT NULL,
  lexscore UNSIGNED INT DEFAULT NULL,
  gramscoreA UNSIGNED INT DEFAULT NULL,
  gramscoreB UNSIGNED INT DEFAULT NULL,
  gramscoreC UNSIGNED INT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(userID, wordID)
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Could you provide me with a link to a tutorial or something please, as I'm not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: Ok, so, everything I've found myself on this tells me that JOIN allows me to display and retrieve data which is _already in_ separate tables. I'm struggling to see how I can use JOIN to store values that are unique to each point of intersection between the tables.

Comment: A "join table" is a table, that is ment to "connect" two other tables: In your case, it would link the user table with the words table, adding the scores to these links. In essence a row in this table would say "User X has scores values a,b,c and d for word Y". The SQL construct `JOIN` is what you use to query those links.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks. So the main thing I need to do is to figure out how to construct a join table. Presumably that's possible in PhPmyAdmin

Comment: I spelt out the necessary columns in my answer - the IDs of word and user and the scores.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But what I need to figure out now is how to make a join table. Thanks for your help. You have answered my question: the most appropriate option is to use a "join table".

Comment: Thank you again. I just figured out that I can mark this as question answered, which is what I've done.